# Internal links on a web page doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, hyperlink

I have an issue with Google Chrome on one of the pages I have been developing.

```
<li><a href="#top">Start</a></li>
   <li><a href="assets/files/Resume.pdf">Resume</a></li>
   <li><a href="#testimonials">Testimonials</a></li>
   <li><a href="#dvcontact">Contact</a></li>
```

I cannot get internal links on the page to work. The page does not navigate to the testimonials section or the contact section. Why doesn't this work?

Things I tried:

1. I tried wrapping the sections element around a div but this doesn't
   work too.
2. I got the start to work by using a #top anchor which is still supported by all browsers.
3. I tried using Edge and Firefox browsers and it works on both.

The website is available online at https://www.ashutoshysingh.com/.

**Note:** The issue occurs specifically in Chrome. I have tested on both v65 and v67 using Windows 10.

Edit-
4. I have also tried running W3C validator and the page is validated.

Comment: can you tell us what plugins you are using? It could be doing something to events or links with a hash.

Comment: That doesn't explain then why Edge and Firefox is working properly. That's why I have marked it as a Chrome-specific issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using the `jQuery.localScroll` plugin for animated-scrolling to the element the hash points to and it probably fails because somewhere inside, it sniffs the browser and employs the old top-level scrolling algorithm (where `<body>` is scrolled rather than `<html>`). I advise you to update all of the related plugins/jQuery.

`#top` works simply because there is no such element on the page, so jQuery.localScroll does not interfere and lets the browser do what it does.

Chrome 61 switched the top-level scrolling mechanism to use `<html>`, like the standards require and like other browsers already follow. 
https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6386758136627200

(I verified it works on Chrome 60)

You can read about one of the similar cases that was resolved by updating a badly-coded library on which the website depended -
https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/chromium-discuss/0j4ewHdP2Gk/Dut0CbPMAQAJ

Comment: thanks for looking at the issue. Simply updating localScroll did the trick. I looked at the code and didn't find any browser sniffing. And if Chrome followed standards other browsers were already following, why didn't it work in the latest version of Chrome (67) but did in Firefox? I am still curious..

Comment: I mentioned in the answer... "somewhere inside, it sniffs the browser and employs the old top-level scrolling algorithm (where <body> is scrolled rather than <html>)". "sniffs the browser" algorithmically means - if the user agent string contains "WebKit" (Chrome, Safari, Samsung Internet, Opera, Edge...) then use `<body>` rather than `<html>`, otherwise use `<html>`. Something like that. The latest update of the library probably  changed the detection to feature detection (`document.scrollingElement` returns the element to use) with a fallback to browser sniffing for older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Actually what i have observed is that when we remove `li` tag around`<a href="#testimonial">` it starts working
i would suggest you to keep `<a href=""><li>..</li></a>`

But i have not been able to figure out the proper reason because same start is working properly

Comment: thanks for helping! start works because all modern browsers have a default implementation for #top. It needn't be an element on the page.